# Why are MS browsers converting my array of objects into an array of arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I'm returning an array of objects from our product API to hydrate our static front end, but all Microsoft browsers appear to be converting this array of 52 product objects into an array of neatly broken up arrays with 10 objects each.

According to our error reporting system this bug only popped up midday on March 6th. We haven't committed any changes to the code since before the bug first exposed itself.

**Example of array returned from API**

```
[
    {product object},
    {product object},
    {product object},
    {product object},
    {product object},
    {product object},
    ... So on through product 52
]
```

**Example of product array variable returned via the console in Microsoft Edge**

```
[
  [
    {product object},
    {product object},
    {product object},
    {product object},
    {product object},
    ... So on through product 9
  ],
  [Array Products 10 - 19],
  [Array Products 20 - 29],
  [Array Products 30 - 39],
  [Array Products 40 - 49],
  [Array Products 50 - 52]
 ]
```

Has anyone else experienced a similar issue with MS browsers over the past week?

My current status after troubleshooting this morning = WAT? Any leads would be helpful!

Comment: `JSON.stringify(array, null, 2)` <--- Will show everything!

Comment: It's not a conversion, it's a console representation for your convenience.

Comment: Thanks @Ele and @KoshVery! The second I submitted my question that thought cross my mind. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Update: It's not a conversion, it's a console representation for your convenience.

The array console representation was just a red herring in a different issue we're troubleshooting. Appreciate the input, everyone!